# Why is "Find All" in Sublime Text 2 so slow?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I'm trying to switch from Coda to Sublime Text 2 as I like much of what the latter has to offer.

However "find all" inside a project directory seems to be sooo slow. I've grown accustomed to using "find all" often in Coda and results appear very fast. *Am I missing something in Sublime?*

#### UPDATE

I may have discovered a helpful tip, adding an "include filter" made **finding** much faster:
`*.js,*.php,*.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have discovered a helpful tip, adding an "include filter" made finding much faster:  `*.js,*.php,*.html`